# How to fix the 'view not found' on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I made a Laravel project.  When I went to deploy it, I get this message:

```
View [back.home] not found.
```

But my view is define on my web.php:

```
Route::get('back/home', 'Back\HomeController@index')->name('back.home');
```

And on my HomeController:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('back.home');
}
```

Before deployment, I made the composer and artisan command:

- `php artisan cache:clear`
- `php artisan route:clear`
- `php artisan config:clear`
- `composer update`

I don't know why it didn't work.

Comment: I have never had to use the full namespace to specify my controller, allthough all of my controllers are in the \App\Http\Controllers namespace. Is there any reason you are not in that namespace, or having to give the full path name? Also, what is the directory structure of your views? is there a views/back/home.blade.php? Also you can simplify your code. The route itself can return the view in a closure.

Comment: Is there a file named `resources/views/back/home.blade.php`? That's where `view('back.home')` will look.

Answer (score 3):

Old question but still no correct answer.  Both OP and the only other (at the time of writing) answer here are confusing the *route* with the *view*.

In the `web.php` routes file, `->name('back.home')` [names the *route*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes).  That route can later be referenced when using [the `route()` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-route), eg like this: `route('back.home')`.

But here the controller method in question is not using that named route, it is simply returning a *view*: `return view('back.home')`.  In this case, Laravel is looking for [the corresponding Blade file](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views) at `resources/views/back/home.blade.php`.  And as the error says:

> View [back.home] not found.

That file is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing

```
Route::get('back/home', 'Back/HomeController@index')->name('Back.home');
```

To This.

```
Route::get('/home', 'Back/HomeController@index')->name('Back.home');
```

Because as the error clearly says laravel is having issues finding your view.

Check your view once again!

Comment: Notice the capital **B** within the route name if you’re just copying and pasting into your `web.php` file.

Answer (score -2):

Heroku doesn't understand '.' so use like this all route and view -:

```
public function index()
{
return view('back/home');   /replace this '.' to '/'
}
```

its working and i solved this error

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit more?

Comment: @Hoargarth please chake again i edited my answer

Comment: Heroku understands `.` just fine.